# How can I display the text emphasised when using adb shell input keyevent 19/20?

Tags: adb

I'm new using adb shell commands and my idea is to use keyevents 19/20 (up/down buttons) so I can access different menus in the android settings. Once I use the first keyevent, there is one section emphasised in grey to know where the system is "pointing", so If I use a keyevent 66 the device itself will open the menu in that section.

My idea is to access different menus using keyevents 19|20|66, the problem is I don't really know how can i direct my code. I thought about displaying the text emphasised but I don't know the commands to do this task. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand what you are asking for, especially at is unclear what "DUT" means and also what "section emphasised in grey" you mean. Please edit your question and describe in details what you are trying to do and also the app you want to send key events to.

Comment: @Robert Usually DUT = Device Under Test.